# Deleting a variables (pointer) value is not deleting the value it points to

Tags: python, linked-list

I am coding up an implementation of a linked list, the linked list class and it's node look like this:

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self, data, next = None):
        self.element = data
        self.next = next

class LinkedList:
    def __init__(self, head):
        self.head = head

    def insert(self, next):
        node = self.head
        while node.next:
            node = node.next

        node.next = next

    def remove(self, element):
        node = self.head
        while node:
            if node.element == element:
                if node.next:
                    node.element = node.next.element;
                    node.next = node.next.next;
                else:
                    print(node.element)
                    node = None;
                break;
            node = node.next

    def get(self, element):
        node = self.head
        while node:
            if node.element == element:
                return node
            node = node.next
        return None
```

I am testing the remove method, and it is not working when I try to remove the last element of the linked list. In this instance the last element should be set to 'None', as you can see in the snippet below (which is included in the class above).

```
def remove(self, element):
    node = self.head
    while node:
        if node.element == element:
            if node.next:
                node.element = node.next.element;
                node.next = node.next.next;
            else:
                node = None; #this will be fired
            break;
        node = node.next
```

However, the last element is not removed and I'm not sure why. I assumed `node` will be a pointer to the last element and the value will be set to `none`, however it is not being deleted. Here is the test which is failing:

```
class Test(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_remove_node(self):
        head = Node('a', Node('b', Node('c')));
        ll = LinkedList(head);
        ll.remove('c');
        self.assertEqual(head.element, 'a');
        self.assertEqual(head.next.element, 'b');
        print(head.next.next.element);
        self.assertIsNone(head.next.next);

if __name__ == "__main__":
    unittest.main()
```

Comment: `node` is technically a pointer (or "reference") to an element. If you set it to `None`, this pointer is set but neither the element itself is modified nor any other pointers to the same element are changed.

Comment: While not outright wrong, I find your (inconsistent) use of semicolons subtly unsettling :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`node` is a temporary local variable that contains an *additional* reference to the node of interest. Setting it to `None` does not alter the structure of the list any more than updating it at every iteration of the loop does:

```
                node
                  v
head -> a -> b -> c -> None
```

vs

```
                       node
                         v
head -> a -> b -> c -> None
```

To properly change the contents of the list, you have to update the pointer in the previous node. You can do this by keeping track of the parent as you iterate:

```
def remove(self, element):
     node, parent = self.head, None
     while node:
         if node.element == element:
              if parent:
                  parent.next = node.next
              else:
                  self.head = node.next
              break
          node, parent = node.next, node
```

You never need to copy elements, and you never need to look past `node.next`. Simply bypassing the node containing the element of interest is sufficient.